# Cannot add event listeners to cloned elements with JQuery - for CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, css-animations

I am making a toggle button using some SVG elements that are animated with CSS animation / @Keyframes.

As you would expect, you click the 'on' element (which in this case is a green svg circle) the class changes to one with the CSS animation present and the element transitions to its 'off' positio (a red svg circle). That works and I can get to that point.

...however, if you want to get the animation going just once whenever the element is clicked, and in reverse, the use of CSS animations requires the following method. Cloning the element, change the class of the new element, and delete the old one.

The issue here is that you cannot initialise the on click events when your JS script first loads, because 'off' element, for example, does not yet exist.

In turn, I need a JQuery function which can:
take the event target

-make a clone

-change the class of the clone to 'leftright' if the pre-existing class is 'Start' or 'rightleft' / change it to 'rightleft' if the pre-existing class is 'leftright'.

-add an on click event to that clone to run the same function

-delete the target

Code is here

https://codepen.io/timiland/pen/LYPGOXe

The JQuery code below is what I have that works, if you look at the codepen link I have some commented out code which I tried but could not get to work. I am hoping that someone has an alternate approach.

```
$(".start").click(function animate() {

let el = $(this); let newone = el.clone(true); $(newone).removeClass().addClass('ltor');

newone.insertAfter(el); el.remove();

});
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(el)` to convert the `e.target` DOM element to jQuery object.

Also, you can use `addClass` method to add 'leftright' and 'rightleft' classes.

```js
$(".start").click(function restart(e) {
  let el = e.target;
  let newone = $(el).clone(true);
  if ($(this).first().is(".start, .rightleft")) {
    $(newone).removeClass().addClass('leftright');
    $(newone).on('click', restart);
  } else {
    $(newone).removeClass().addClass('rightleft');
    $(newone).on('click', restart);
  }
  newone.insertAfter(el);
  el.remove();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

svg {
  height: 150px;
  width: 225px;
}

.start {
  transform: translate(-37.5px, 0);
}

.leftright {
  animation: redtogreen 1.5s linear 1 forwards;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.rightleft {
  animation: redtogreen 1.5s linear 1 reverse forwards;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

@keyframes redtogreen {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(0px, -37.5px) scale(1);
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg) translate(0px, -50px) scale(0.5);
  }
  48% {
    fill: #1e8239;
  }
  50% {
    fill: red;
    transform: rotate(0) translate(0px, 0) scale(0.1);
  }
  66% {
    fill: red;
    transform: rotate(-25deg) translate(0px, 50px) scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    fill: red;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(0px, 37.5px) scale(1);
  }
}

#overlay {
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: appear 1.5s linear 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  39% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  63% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  69% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path class="underlay" stroke-width="50" d="M75 75 l75 0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="beige" />

  <circle class="start" cx="112.5" cy="75" r="20" fill="#1e8239"/>
    
<!-- <path id="overlay" stroke-width="50" d="M75 75 l75 0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#F0F0F0" /> -->
</svg>
```

Comment: [I have added an effect to the code now so the ball flies around the back of the graphic.](https://codepen.io/timiland/pen/LYPGOXe)  You might be interested to see what the end product I was aiming for was,